# PHP, move to next item on list

Tags: php

So I'm making a script where a user can check whether a website is up, I have the website checking part, but now I need to figure out the part where it actually reads a list.

It is annoying for a user having to enter one website at a time, so I want to take the time to make it so a user can do something like this, they can put in a long list of websites, they will each be individually read, and marked online, or offline.

Example:

> google.com
>
> facebook.com
>
> yahoo.com

The only thing I need help with, is how can I make it loop through each line?  It checks one line, and then moves to the next.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing, I honestly have no idea how to go about doing this.  Even just a small amount of information could lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
<?PHP

$string = $_POST['url_list'];

foreach(explode("\n", $string) as $line) {

    // do something

}

?>
```

If using \n is NOT working you can also try using \r\n instead.

Comment: Having a new problem, I'm having difficulty to get it to read just the one line of site, and print out "online" or "offline" next to it.  It is printing out the whole list of sites.   Basically, I need it to read one line, echo out "offline" or "offline" and move to the next.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $sites = $_POST['listofsites'];

    // Assuming list of sites in in a textarea and separated by a new line
    $sites = explode("\n", $sites);

    foreach ($sites as $site) 
    {
        // do your thing   
    }
?>
```

Comment: Having a new problem, I'm having difficulty to get it to read just the one line of site, and print out "online" or "offline" next to it.  It is printing out the whole list of sites.   Basically, I need it to read one line, echo out "offline" or "offline" and move to the next.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<textarea name="site_list">

</textarea>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $sites = array_filter(explode("\n", str_replace("\r","\n", $_POST['site_list'])),'trim');
    foreach($sites as $site){

         // site checking code here
    }
?>
```

This gets a list of sites from a textarea and cleans up the list removing any empty lines or empty characters before or after the url.

Comment: Having a new problem, I'm having difficulty to get it to read just the one line of site, and print out "online" or "offline" next to it. It is printing out the whole list of sites. Basically, I need it to read one line, echo out "offline" or "offline" and move to the next

Comment: Sounds like another question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to take the input as comma separated and then explode the string as comma delemeter.

```
$string = "yahoo.com,google.com";
 $explode = explode(',',$string);
 foreach ($explode as $e){
 //do whatever you want to do
 }
```